# ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (50)

Tags: python-3.x

Hey there awesome peeps,
I am trying to retrieve some trend information based on some keywords that I have in a list (1000 keywords). In order to minimize the chance of getting blocked by Google I have a cutoff period of 50 and a 10 second pause. At the moment I get an error saying that my Length of value does not match the length of the index. This fails on the

df3['Trend'] = trends

If anyone can help I will really appreciate it.

Thanks!

```
    !pip install pytrends

import pandas as pd
import json
import time
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

get_gsc_file = "/content/Queries.csv"
sortby = "Clicks"
cutoff = 50
pause = 10
timeframe = "today 3-m"
geo = "US"

df = pd.read_csv(get_gsc_file, encoding='utf-8')
df.sort_values(by=[sortby], ascending=False, inplace=True)
df = df[:cutoff]

d = {'Keyword': [], sortby:[], 'Trend': []}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
keywords = []
trends = []
metric = df[sortby].tolist()
up = 0
down = 0
flat = 0
na = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  keyword = row['Top queries']
  pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360, retries=2, backoff_factor=0.1)
  kw_list = [keyword]
  pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe=timeframe, geo=geo, gprop='')
  df2 = pytrends.interest_over_time()
  keywords.append(keyword)
try:
  trend1 = int((df2[keyword][-5] + df2[keyword][-4] + df2[keyword][-3])/3)
  trend2 = int((df2[keyword][-4] + df2[keyword][-3] + df2[keyword][-2])/3)
  trend3 = int((df2[keyword][-3] + df2[keyword][-2] + df2[keyword][-1])/3)

  if trend3 > trend2 and trend2 > trend1: 
    trends.append('UP')
    up+=1
  elif trend3 < trend2 and trend2 < trend1: 
    trends.append('DOWN')
    down+=1
  else:
    trends.append('FLAT')
    flat+=1
except:
  trends.append('N/A')
  na+=1
  time.sleep(pause)

df3['Keyword'] = keywords
df3['Trend'] = trends
df3[sortby] = metric

def colortable(val):
    if val == 'DOWN':
        color="lightcoral"
    elif val == 'UP':
        color = "lightgreen"
    elif val == 'FLAT':
        color = "lightblue"
    else:
        color = 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df3 = df3.style.applymap(colortable)

total = len(trends)
print("Up: " + str(up) + " | " + str(round((up/total)*100,0)) + "%")
print("Down: " + str(down) + " | " + str(round((down/total)*100,0)) + "%")
print("Flat: " + str(flat) + " | " + str(round((flat/total)*100,0)) + "%")
print("N/A: " + str(na) + " | " + str(round((na/total)*100,0)) + "%")

df3
```

Comment: Have you inspected the values of `keywords` and `trends`? They should have the same length. Also it appears as if your indentation is incorrect: the `try` statement should probably be inside the `for` loop but it is separate now

Comment: @jan that was the issue. The damn indentation.